# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError for Solr Queries Including Grouping And Sorting

Tags: java, solr, lucene, jetty

Solr is giving me `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` when I am grouping and doing sorting on multiple fields. The query runs fine for a condition matching small no of documents.

This is the query i am firing:

```
q=*%3A*&fq=DOCUMENT_TYPE%3APROPERTY&fq=%7B%21tag%3DCITY_ID%7DCITY_ID%3A%282%29&fq=%7B%21tag%3DLOCALITY_ID%7DLOCALITY_ID%3A%2850186%29&fq=%7B%21tag%3DUNIT_TYPE%7DUNIT_TYPE%3A%28"Apartment"+OR+"Villa"%29&rows=9999&start=0&sort=DISPLAY_ORDER+asc%2CPROJECT_PRIORITY+asc%2CPROJECT_ID+desc&group=true&group.ngroups=true&group.limit=-1&group.field=PROJECT_ID&group.sort=BEDROOMS+asc%2CSIZE+asc
```

Here is the resulting stacktrace.

```
SEVERE: null:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.sendError(SolrDispatchFilter.java:469)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:297)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1337)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:484)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:486)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:413)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:351)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:47)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:890)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:944)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:634)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:66)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:254)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Query runs fine when I remove sorting and grouping part. So, problem obviously lies there.

Following is the memory I have allocated to solr at startup:

```
java -Xms512M -Xmx2048M -jar start.jar
```

which I thought should be more than enough for my needs:

```
Total no of documents in my collection: 237816
Total no of matching documents in the query: 910
```

Here is the extract of schema.xml corresponding to the fields that are being used in sorting and grouping:

```
<field name="DISPLAY_ORDER" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="PROJECT_PRIORITY" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="PROJECT_ID" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="BEDROOMS" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="SIZE" type="sdouble" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<fieldType name="sdouble" class="solr.SortableDoubleField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hi, I am also getting the similar issue recently. Any updates you did those helped you? I will be so grateful.

Comment: @qasimzee: i increased the memory allocated to JVM and postponed the permanent solution... please let me know if you find a permanent solution.

Comment: Yesterday, I also did the same. I am also trying to find the permanent solution as our index will past 10 Gigs very soon :)